# Conditional logic depens on culture settings. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation

I have bunch  pages and I need to validate data there. If culture for example "es-ES" I should use one validation logic, if culture "en-US" than another validation logic. For example I need validate phone number. Minimum length is 11 digits. For other culture 9 digits. How can I do this? Some patterns or other decisions?

Comment: I think your question is leading to do all the things manually by your self defined logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If localizing, you should be using satellite assemblies for localization - this will also allow you to set culture specific RegEx expressions for validation (phone number formats etc).

Comment: This is the best approach, makes it easier supporting new cultures later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the current culture by checking Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name. Is that what you mean?

Comment: not exactly. I mean how to implement validation logic for specific culture.

Comment: In that case, you could use something like: string culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name; if (culture == "es-ES") { // do something } if (culture == "en-US") { // do something else }. Then, for the validation logic itself, I'd recommend RegEx expressions, like Oded proposed.

Comment: Yes. I am doing exactly in this way. But I would like to make it in another way.

Comment: I guess you could create a static const Dictionary<string, string> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) somewhere in your class, prefilled with the culture as key and a RegEx expression as the value. Then, in the validation code, you could retrieve the correct expression from the dictionary and use that. That would give 'cleaner' code I guess (not so much ifs).

Answer (score 0):

What if my browser is set to en-US because I'm a us national but I'm in spain with a spanish mobile number?

Comment: I have web-config. I have field Culture. P.S. the question very good:).